# How do I make certain pages invisible for all but some users in MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki, access-control

I do not want our wiki to be visible to the public. Only registered users should be able to view the wiki.

There only seem to be options to block specific users or IP addresses. I want to block all except registered users.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Preventing_access

Specifically the 'Simple Private Wiki' information;

> **Simple private wiki**
>
> For the common use case of "a private wiki, for oneself and approved others", you need to:
>
> Restrict viewing
>
> Restrict editing
>
> Restrict account creation

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks alot. Could you also specify in your answer how to restrict viewing and account creation. Unfortunately, mediawiki.org is blocked at work, because it is free software.

Comment: Info as a pdf - http://www.filejumbo.com/Download/238BA52E4DB10A4D